# Icon Composer location

Tags: xcode, icons

I don't have Xcode 4 yet but I need to know where Icon Composer is located (and the exact Xcode 4 version).

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xcode 3 or 4 up to 4.2 I believe, you can find Icon Composer in this location...

> ```
> /Developer/Applications/Utilities
> ```

However, if you have one of the newest versions of Xcode (from the App Store) Icon composer can be found in this location

> ```
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications
> ```

To get to this location you can navigate to your applications folder, right click Xcode and click "show package contents."

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, is it possible that you meant to say

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications

instead of 

/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Applications

? Anyway, could you link a screenshot of this tree, in the Finder?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'll edit .app into my answer and I have an explanation as to how to get to Icon Composer like this underneath that URL. I can't upload a screenshot right now as I'm not at my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in /Developer/Applications/Utilities, assuming you installed Xcode in /Developer.

Comment: It might of been, I only know the location for xcode 4. But the location of the Icon Composer is /installLocation/Applications/Utilities